# Multi Client in server - WebSocket C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

how are you? I hope that you are good, I have a question, how can I do to the server consume multi clients? I put all my code

Server

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Consola
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ip = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 8080;
            var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection…", ip, port);

            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // enter to an infinite cycle to be able to handle every change in stream
            while (true)
            {
                while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
                while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

                byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
                string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                    // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                    // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                    // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                    // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                    string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                    string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                    byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                    string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                    // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                    byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                        "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                    stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                        mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"
                    int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                        offset = 2;
                    ulong msglen = (ulong)(bytes[1] & 0b01111111);

                    if (msglen == 126)
                    {
                        // bytes are reversed because websocket will print them in Big-Endian, whereas
                        // BitConverter will want them arranged in little-endian on windows
                        msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                        offset = 4;
                    }
                    else if (msglen == 127)
                    {
                        // To test the below code, we need to manually buffer larger messages — since the NIC's autobuffering
                        // may be too latency-friendly for this code to run (that is, we may have only some of the bytes in this
                        // websocket frame available through client.Available).
                        msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                        offset = 10;
                    }

                    if (msglen == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
                    }
                    else if (mask)
                    {
                        byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                        byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                        offset += 4;

                        for (ulong i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                            decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[(ulong)offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Prueba simple de WebSocket</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>
                <textarea cols="60" rows="6" id="cajadetexto"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="boton" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <div id="salida"></div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        textarea {
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }

        #salida {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #salida > p {
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
        }

        #salida span {
            color: blue;
        }

        #salida span.error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/";
            const websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

            $(document).on("click", "#boton", onClickButton);

            websocket.onopen = (e) => {
                writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
                doSend("WebSocket rocks");
            };

            websocket.onclose = (e) => {
                writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
            };

            websocket.onmessage = (e) => {
                writeToScreen(`<span>RESPONSE: ${e.data}</span>`);
            };

            websocket.onerror = (e) => {
                writeToScreen(`<span class="error">ERROR:</span> ${e.data}`);
            };

            function doSend(message) {
                writeToScreen(`SENT: ${message}`);
                websocket.send(message);
            }

            function writeToScreen(message) {
                $("#salida").append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
            }

            function onClickButton() {
                var text = $("#cajadetexto").val();

                text && doSend(text);
                $("#cajadetexto").val("");
                $("#cajadetexto").focus();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I based my code on this link:
https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/files/en-us/web/api/websockets_api/writing_websocket_server/index.md?plain=1

Thanks and I wait your answers.

**UPGRADE 23/12/2022 12:05**

Hi, finally i could implement the threads to the multi clients in the server, this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Consola
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(
            IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 
            8080
        );
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tcpListener.Start();
            while(true)
            {
                Thread nuevoHilo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
                nuevoHilo.Start();
            }
        }

        private static void Listeners()
        {
            Socket client = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client:" + client.RemoteEndPoint + " now connected to server.");
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);

                while (true)
                {
                    while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
                    while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
                    string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                        // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                        // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                        // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                        // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                        string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                        string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                        byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                        string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                        // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                        byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                        stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool fin = (bytes
[o]& 0b10000000) != 0,
                            mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"
                        int opcode = bytes
[o]& 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                            offset = 2;
                        ulong msglen = (ulong)(bytes[1] & 0b01111111);

                        if (msglen == 126)
                        {
                            // bytes are reversed because websocket will print them in Big-Endian, whereas
                            // BitConverter will want them arranged in little-endian on windows
                            msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                            offset = 4;
                        }
                        else if (msglen == 127)
                        {
                            // To test the below code, we need to manually buffer larger messages — since the NIC's autobuffering
                            // may be too latency-friendly for this code to run (that is, we may have only some of the bytes in this
                            // websocket frame available through client.Available).
                            msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                            offset = 10;
                        }

                        if (msglen == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
                        }
                        else if (mask)
                        {
                            byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                            byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                            offset += 4;

                            for (ulong i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                                decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[(ulong)offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need that the client view can notify the other clients messages and prevent the OutOfMemoryException when I leave the system very quiet.
This image shows my situation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsHFe.png)

Comment: Do you have some special reasons for using web sockets, or do you just want to make a few computers talk to each other? If it is the later there are easier protocols and libraries to use that take care of many if the internal details.

Comment: The idea is using web sockets to the real time notification, but the server should the clients amount that use him.

Comment: Many other protocols should handle "real time" just as well as web sockets, at least as "real time" as networking get. Most should also handle arbitrary number of clients without issue.